# I cant echo the username in OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I cant figure out why I keep getting 2 errors.

Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs......index.php on line 8

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs.......index.php on line 8

```
Heres my DB CLASS


<?php
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private   $_pdo, 
        $_query, 
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x =1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
             $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
             $x++;
            }

        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }   
    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where)=== 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=' );

        $field     = $where[0];
        $operator  = $where[1];
        $value     = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}   

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
}
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));
if(!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No User';
    } else {
        foreach($user->results() as $user) {
        echo $user->$username, '<br>';
    }
}
```

The connection to my DB works, my prepare works successfully, my bindValue works successfully, my count method works as well, if I try to get a user that does not exist from the db it returns false/'No User', but when i use foreach to echo the actual username I get those 2 errors and that's where I am stuck. Because $user is defined by the getInstance shouldn't that define the $username and therefore not be an empty property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to call `$user->username` not `$user->$username`.

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));
if(!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No User';
    } else {
        foreach($user->results() as $user) {
        echo $user->username, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG I feel like such a tool... Ive been stuck for 2 days on this.. The big idiot I am would like to thank you